# custom CSS not applied to div

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, style

i have the following css:

```
.THIS .noErrorStyle {
    padding-bottom: 8rem; 
    padding-left:2rem; 
    padding-right:2rem;
}

.THIS .errorStyle {
    padding-bottom: 4.3rem !important; 
    padding-left:2rem; 
    padding-right:2rem;
}

.THIS .removedPositionFixed {
    position: inherit !important;
}
```

and the following div in a lightning component:

```
<div class="{!v.meetingComponentSource == 'CreateMeeting' ? 'slds-modal slds-fade-in-open removedPositionFixed' : 'slds-modal slds-fade-in-open'}">
```

when i load the component, i can see the class in the HTML, but the style is not applied:
[image]

any idea what is the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the div is the first element in the component, the div is also `.THIS`, so `.THIS .removedPositionFixed` won't be found. Changing it to `.THIS.removedPositionFixed` (no space between `.THIS` and `.removedPositionFixed`) worked.

Thanks to [Xander](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/37566/xander) for the comment that helped me solve the issue.